# CR2 files "Currently unavailable"

Tags: darktable

Only recently when I tried to import my Canon 700D CR2 photos, they appear in the lighttable section but when I select and click darkroom I receive an "....image is currently unavailable".

I'm running Darktable on a ASUS x550 with 12Gb RAM on Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I checked permissions on all CR2 images and ALL are set to full "rxw".

I'd really appreciate some help.
Hal

Comment: Are they really on the disk with a size that is compatible with what you camera usually produces (20MB+ normally...). Have the files been changed in any way (in particular with ExifTool)?

Comment: Are you able to open the images on any other devices? may also be worth looking into converting CR2 to jpeg or similar and see if you're then able to open to see if it's something to do with the data itself.

Comment: Are you using the current (2.6 as of this post) version of darktable?

Comment: In response to your question Junky, I was using the version offered by Synaptic 2.4.1. but as I said in a previous response that it was displaying all CR2 files as thumbnails in Lighttable, but when selected said they were "unavailable". Yes all these files open easily in Raw Therapee. I'll go looking for the latest version of Darktable and try again. Thank you for your time and response. Hal

Comment: I have the same problem and its driving me insane.  The files open fine with Cannon's DPP RAW editor, and nothing was ever altered about the files.  At first it was just a few CR2s DT failed to read, but soon it couldn't read any of the several hundred I had loaded.  New bug to report?

Answer (score 2):

Darktable does not "import" images.  It remembers them, their file location and their thumbnail.  However, to do anything with them, the file actually needs to be present at the expected location, typically by plugging the memory card into a reader or connecting the camera with a USB cable.  If it isn't, you get that error message.

Comment: Thank you for your response user81606, the action was strange because I had been using Darktable the day before with no such problems. All my RAW images are in a separate folder which DT recognises. However first thing this morning I installed Raw Therapee and am impresssed, it is easier to use, maybe not as powerful, but quite enough for me. Also it integrated without asking with GIMP. I'll keep trying with DT, but suspect forfuture raw processing I'll be using RT Thank you again for your concern and response. Hal.