# Darktable: How to fix "Image .. is currently unavailable" (after having moved imaged to different (sub-)folder on drive)?

Tags: darktable

After having moved a bunch of photos to a (sub-)folder on the drive, darktable no longer finds them and when double-clicking the resp. thumbnail (in darktable's lighttable), the error message pops up: "Image .. is currently unavailable".

Is there really no way to fix this by a click-of-a-button? Does darktable (v.3.8.0) expect the user to manually chuck out all offending thumbnails after having moved the images on disk?

---

Related links:

https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/3632 (**feature request**)

[After exporting from Darktable, I continue getting a message stating, "IMG...CR2 file is currently unavailable"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119712/after-exporting-from-darktable-i-continue-getting-a-message-stating-img-cr2) (not a question)

[CR2 files "Currently unavailable"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/104519/cr2-files-currently-unavailable) (an answer without a question)

Answer (score 3):

Reimport the images into Darktable from the new location so Darktable’s database has information about their location.

Use the **Remove** option in the [Selected Images Module](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.8/en/module-reference/utility-modules/lighttable/selected-image/) to remove the incorrect duplicate old entries from the database

The **Move** option of the Selected Images Module can be used to move images between directories while keeping Darktable’s database up to date.

For large scale file moves such as a terabyte from one drive to another, I find it easier to move the files, delete Darktable’s database, and reimport from the new location…even though it can take a few hours, it can run while I sleep. Otherwise I rarely move files around because I have many other things I prefer to file management.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple click-a-button solution but darktable ships a shell script `purge_non_existing_images.sh` to remove all non-existing images (aka the images that have been moved) from the database, see the [documentation](https://darktable-org.github.io/dtdocs/en/special-topics/program-invocation/purge_non_existing_images_sh/).

To add the images from the new location back to darktable, you need to re-import them manually as if they were new images.